# Limit user to input email to just first part (can enter just name up to @ sign)

Tags: email, import, limit

I have form inside popup windows in which i enter user details for specific company (first/last name, password/confirm pass... etc.) I want to limit email input field to just enter first part of email format. In other words, i want user to input his name or anything else, and other part after @ will be generated according to selected company from dropdown list.

Lets say that user can enter  in x spaces xxxx@company.com

If anyone have sugestion for best way to do that, i will be very thankful. For information, i'm working with angular2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If talking about UI design, I think the best solution is to let the user to select the company name first and use an input control similar to [Bootstrap Input Groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups).

[image]

You'll need to change the domain according to your selection.

Comment: Yes, I could try that ... seems like fine solution for my needs. Limit user to import username, and email will generate as follows, and I could change rest of email part on company change. Thanks